# Why there's no session ID in http login response in Python?

Tags: python, http, post, authentication

My server successfully responses with cookie header to my browser client. But there's a trouble with Python. I dont see any cookie header with session ID.

My code:

```
import requests

url = 'http://192.168.0.100/login'
values = {'email': 'dude@example.com',
          'password': '2314'}

with requests.session() as s:
    s.get(url)
    r = s.post(url, data=values)
    print(r.headers)`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you do redirect on the server after authentication and client doesn't get any cookie header. Try to include redirect restriction to request:

```
r = s.post(url, data=values, allow_redirects=False)
```

Then you access any cookie header by:

`r.cookies['HEADER_NAME']`